# Access data from sqlite database?

Tags: android

I am trying to retrive data from the  database but when I call `showData()`, the application stops. Everything looks good but I don't know why it happens. Please help, I am new in android.

This belongs to the main activity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button allContact,addContact,editContact,searchContact,deleteContact;
    EditText name,phone;Button add;
    TextView t,t2;
    String dbString="";
    String dbString2="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        allContact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        addContact =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        editContact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        searchContact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        deleteContact =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);

        addContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.addcontectlayout_main);
                name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);

                add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String takeName=name.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                        String takePhone=phone.getText().toString();


                        ContactDatabase onbOfContactDatabase=new ContactDatabase(getBaseContext());
                        onbOfContactDatabase.insertContact(takeName,takePhone);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "data is inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        allContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AllContact.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

This class comes after intend start:

```
public class AllContact extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.allcontactlayout_main);

      TextView  t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
       TextView t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        ContactDatabase onbOfContactDatabase=new ContactDatabase(getBaseContext());

       Cursor get= onbOfContactDatabase.showData();
      //when i call showData application stope.


    }
}
```

This belongs to the database:

```
public class ContactDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="totalContact.db";
    public static final  String TABLE_NAME="contact";
    public static final  String NAME="name";
    public static final  String PHONE="phone";

    public ContactDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("craete table contact" +
                    "(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, phone text)");
        }catch(android.database.SQLException e){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertContact(String nam,String mob){

        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(NAME,nam);
        contentValues.put(PHONE,mob);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }

    public Cursor showData(){

        db=this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM contact", null);
        return res;

    }
}
```

logcat is:

```
01-06 21:51:36.282 177-177/? A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xa2be0 passed to dlfree
06-08 21:53:00.359 11680-11680/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.firstproject.contactinfo, PID: 11680
                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contact (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM contact
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
                                                       at com.example.firstproject.contactinfo.ContactDatabase.showData(ContactDatabase.java:58)
                                                       at com.example.firstproject.contactinfo.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: Please edit the question with the **complete** logcat of the error you're getting. Without it, it's quite less likely anybody can help you.

Comment: Also, why is `setContentView(R.layout.allcontactlayout_main);` in the `onClickListener`. Move that line to `onCreate` method, **before** initializing any of the `view` elements. (right after `super.onCreate`).

Comment: @Vucko setContentView(R.layout.allcontactlayout_main); becouse i want all element of database shown in "allcontactlayout_main" layout.

Comment: That is not the proper way to do that. That line initializes the view for the activity, and you cannot FIND the `allContact` button (I'm assuming it's button) before you've set the content view. It is that content view that **holds** the button, and on that view the method `findViewById` gets called.

Comment: Just try what I'm suggesting you and you'll see that it works.

Comment: @Vucko i try like this, make new class extends activity and write setContentView(R.layout.allcontactlayout_main); after super.onCreate() but m geting same problem

Comment: Please do post the **whole**  error logcat in the **edited** question...

Comment: @Vucko now i post my all code plese check my code

Comment: You did not post the logcat yet, that's the most integral part.

Comment: @Vucko now i post my logcat status

Comment: This is quite a new error different from the one you had previously. "SQLiteException: no such table: contact" You must debug your code yourself to see why the table is not getting created.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `setContentView(R.layout.allcontactlayout_main)` from the `onClickListener` to `onCreate` method, before initializing any of the view elements (right after `super.onCreate`).

That line initializes the **view** for the activity, and you cannot **FIND** the `allContact` button (I'm assuming it's button) before you've set the content view. It is **that** content view that holds the button and other elements, and on that view the method `findViewById` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

First move your setContentView(R.layout.allcontactlayout_main) from the onClickListener to onCreate method and then

```
public Cursor showData()
{
  SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM contact";
    return database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

}
```

Call database showdata() method

```
ContactDatabase onbOfContactDatabase=new ContactDatabase(YOURACTIVITY.this);
Cursor get= onbOfContactDatabase.showData();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should declare your `TextView t` and `TextView t2` before `onCreate` method. Then initialize them inside of `onCreate` like

`t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);`

and

`t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);`

2) It is better to have two additional methods that are responsible for opening and closing the database. Here is my example of database class that I have created.

```
public class DaysDatabase {

    //some variables

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        //again some code

    }

    public DaysDatabase open(){
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    //your method
    public Cursor showData(){
        Cursor res =  ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM contact", null);
        return res;

    }

    /*
     *    rest of the necessary code
     */
}
```

To understand better have a look at this tutorial:

https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=6&video=16832

The tutorial is spread for several videos but I find them quite useful.